# Generic Types and overriding

Tags: .net, arrays, list, generics

I have a class where I want to implement a function Import with those definitions :

```
1. Public Sub Import(of T)(ByRef Data() as T)

2. Public Sub Import(of T)(ByRef Data(,) as T)

3. Public Sub Import(of T)(ByRef Data()() as T)

4. Public Sub Import(of T)(ByRef Data as List(Of T))

5. Public Sub Import(of T)(ByRef Data as List(Of T()))

6. Public Sub Import(of T)(ByRef Data as List(Of List(Of T)))

7. Public Sub Import(of T)(ByRef Data() as List(Of T))
```

My problem is the compiler is not able to determine the correct Import function when I write :

```
Dim ArrayList as List(of String)() = something
MyClass.Import(ArrayList)
```

I understand why, because 1 and 7 can represent the same thing.

So I've tried to write in my class :

```
Public Sub Import(Of T)(ByRef Data() As T)
    Try
        Select Case True
            Case Data(0).GetType().IsArray
                ImportArrayArrayT(Data)
            Case Data(0).GetType.IsGenericType
                ImportArrayListT(Data)
            Case Else
                ImportArrayT(Data)
        End Select
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub

Protected Sub ImportArrayT(Of T)(ByRef Data() As T)
End Sub

Protected Sub ImportArrayArrayT(Of T)(ByRef Data As T()())
End Sub

Protected Sub ImportArrayListT(Of T)(ByRef Data() As List(Of T))
End Sub
```

But I get an other error on `ImportArrayArrayT(Data)`, `ImportArrayListT(Data)`, and `ImportArrayT(Data)`. The message error says that it's impossible to deduce the type of data from parameter of the method.

I need to use generic types, because I don't care if the type is String, Integer, Double... but I need different code if it's an Array, a List or combination of them (2D max).

So have you any idea to resolve my problem ? I wouldn't code Import function for each Type (String, Integer, ...) and combination of List and Array.

Thanks

Comment: It seems like importing lists and importing single elements are different operations, and should have different function names. You can also use interfaces like `IEnumerable<T>` and `IList<T>` to reduce the number of types you need to handle.

Answer (score 0):

One caution I would offer is not to overthink the plumbing.

If you know how to perform the import for the specific types you can support, consider declaring an interface for your import, then have concrete classes implement the types that can handle your conversion, then just make the interface type the parameter to your function, eg IImportable (for example).

**EDIT: Bit more clarification**

With an interface such as IImportable, you could reduce those Import def's to:

```
Protected Sub Import(of T)(ByRef IImportable(Of T))
```

You could even write an abstract base class to implement the interface, then write concrete implementations for each type from which you want to be able to import.

Just a thought...hope its useful.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the name of (at least) one of the overloads, naming them in a similar way to Add and AddRange on the IList interface. Unless you are using reflection or dynamic language features, the choice of which method to call will be a compile time decision. Your method calling code will always reference one specific overload each time, rather than just `Import`, even though it might feel like it's a dynamic choice when you write that code because you only have to write `Import` without thinking about which one you want to use. It's not like class inheritance where the final choice of method can be changed after compilation depending on the way the type of each instance has inherited the base type. You therefore may as well just change the name of the method that is causing conflict.

If you are aiming for dynamic usage, you may be best having an `Import` method that accepts an object parameter, and then implementing your own type checking of that object to decide which of the existing methods to use for the import, thus allowing you to decide your own order of preference when the interpretation of the input instance is otherwise ambiguous. You would then be able to just call your method with any input (even at runtime) and have it choose your preferred import method. I seem to remember that the `typeof` keyword was made a lot more efficient back when generics were introduced in .NET2 so it might not be as bad a solution as you might initially assume would be the case by avoiding at least some of the generics.

For typeof usage, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ec5kw18(v=vs.80).aspx. The code would look something like:

```
If (input Is TypeOf(List(Of T)))
    ' Import somehow'

Else If (input Is TypeOf(ArrayList(Of T)))
    ' Import some other way'

' etc.'
End If
```

Comment: What you say is interesting, and I've tried to do that (second par of my post), but : (1) I've a problem of casting, and (2) when I use an object parameter, if I use `TheObject.GetType()` it gives me Object and not List(of String). And moreover, it seems hard to know when an object is a list, for array it's ok `GetType.IsArray`, for List I've used `GetType.IsGenericType` but it's not exactly that. 
So If you have an example to manage that, it should be nice !

Comment: Try TypeOf in the edit above... I might not have got the code sample 100% but I've linked to the documentation of it.

Comment: Sorry I though TypeOf was C# writting of GetType. 
However I'm not sure to understand your example. What you write can be include in this function `Public Sub Import(of T)(input as object)`, but in this case what is T ?

Comment: T would be the ultimate type of the object that is wrapped in whatever collection constructs are being used. A generic type parameter does not have to be used in a method parameter - the method can be called by saying `Import(Of T)(myObject)`.

Comment: Ok, I though that program determine T using method parameter. I'll try your solution, it seems very good. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When the compiler is unable to deduce the type of argument, you have to give it a little hint. Try this:

```
Dim ArrayList As List(Of String)()
Module1.Import(Of List(Of String))(ArrayList)
```

Comment: It could be a solution, but if possible I prefer that user don't have to specify explicitly the type. Nevertheless, I was looking for what you say, so thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers, but I think I've found the solution using ParamArray (night is a good help !). If I use this code it seems good :

```
Public Sub Import(Of T)(ByVal ParamArray Data As List(Of T)())
End Sub

Public Sub Import(Of T)(ByVal ParamArray Data()() As T)
End Sub

Public Sub Import(Of T)(ByRef Data(,) As T)
End Sub

Public Sub Import(Of T)(ByRef Data As List(Of List(Of T)))
End Sub

Public Sub Import(Of T)(ByRef Data As List(Of T()))
End Sub
```

If I don't want to distinguish 1D and 2D Array (or List), the compiler find the correct function in all cases. I think I can manage into the sub if it's a 2D or 1D data.

I'll test more things before closing this topic, but for the moment it's ok.

Comment: I would be surprised if ParamArray simplifies the overload resolution, since you can still call the method the same way as you could without ParamArray, but you gain additional ways to call it which I would expect to make it more ambiguous. Are you certain it is calling the overload you expected in these circumstances?

Comment: I'm surprise too, but using ParamArray, I can give a 1D or 2D Array (or List) into the same function and I think it was my problem before. Now whatever T, all Import function are different, so compiler is happy (and me too!).